# Failed to validate newly established connection - Grails 4

Tags: spring, oracle, tomcat, grails, sqlexception

We are using Grails 4 framework for our web application with oracle database. Everything work fine when we host the application locally. However, when we migrated the application to production environment, application is getting disconnected with database server intermittently. On checking the tomcat logs we are getting " SQLexception Failed to validate newly established connection" error.

SQL error

[image]

Application.yml

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post the formatted text of the errors, not images or screenshots.

Comment: Why in the earth would you take a picture of your monitor with a camera. The pictures are horrible. Please at least learn how to take screenshot -- and even better, do what pmdba told you.

Comment: In addition to text instead of screenshots, please share your database connection configuration.  As far as I can tell that is not in your images, and will be relevant to this error.